# how to show confirmation dialog from drop down list?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a grid which display data from database, and i have a custom column in the left side with checkbox, i choose records to be deleted and i have a dropdown list, which will trigger an event in server side to delete records, before i delete those records i want to show a confirmation dialog like "are you sure? with ok and cancel", how to do that? any thought?

i do this :

```
 if(ddlAction.SelectedValue == "Delete")
 {
     string id = string.Empty;
     int i = 0;
     List<int> idx = new List<int>();

     foreach (GridViewRow rowitem in gvDept.Rows)
     {
        CheckBox itemchk = (CheckBox)rowitem.FindControl("cbSelectOne");

        if (itemchk != null & itemchk.Checked)
        {
             id += rowitem.Cells[3].Text.ToString() + ',';
              idx.Add(i);
         }

          i = i + 1;
      }

      id = id.Trim(",".ToCharArray());
      List<string> objRemoveKeys = id.Split(',').ToList();

      if (objRemoveKeys.Count > 0)
      {     
         ddlAction.Attributes.Add("OnChange", "javascript:return confirmDeletion('Are you sure you would like to remove the selected items?');"); // this part not working.

         AirAsiaLinqDataContext LinqDataCtx = new AirAsiaLinqDataContext();

         var record = from a in LinqDataCtx.departements
                      where objRemoveKeys.Contains(a.departementcode)
                      select a;

         LinqDataCtx.departements.DeleteAllOnSubmit(record);
         LinqDataCtx.SubmitChanges();


         for (int j = 0; j < idx.Count; j++)
         {
             gvDept.DeleteRow(idx[j]);
         }
    }

   ddlAction.SelectedValue = "";
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like code-behind (C#) code. Dialogs happen on the client side. You can do this relatively easily with jQuery (or even vanilla JavaScript code), or use something like the Ajax Control Toolkit's `ConfirmButton`:

http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ConfirmButton/ConfirmButton.aspx

For a little more control over the process you can also give JuiceUI a go: http://juiceui.com/controls/dialog

Comment: hi Tieson, yeah it is part of my C# code, i thought we can add some client side event to controls with controlname.attribute.add("")

Comment: @HendraLim That would in theory work, but it's something that needs to be done on the original page load. Adding it in the postback would serve no purpose, as that is all server-side processing. It's hard to tell which one you are doing since you haven't included the entire method. It seems like, since you reference `SelectedValue`, that this is postback handling.

Comment: yep, it is a postback handling, all the code above is in a dropdown list event, well i think your suggestion is the best option i have, many thanks Tieson.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
ddlAction.Attributes.Add("onchange", "return confirm('Are you sure you would like to remove the selected items?');");
```

Comment: i did, was not working either, by the way ddlAction is a dropdownlist control, it is not a button.

Answer (score 0):

you should not only show an alert for confirmation but also check if the user has selected some row or not. below code accomplishes both.

javascript function:

```
function checkIfSelected() {
    if (yourGrid.GetSelectedRowCount() == 0) {
        alert("You must select atleast one.");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to proceed?")) { // This is what you want
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

your dropdownlist:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAction" onChange="javascript:if( checkIfSelected() == false){return false};" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="yourID_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

Comment: hi tariq, i have tried it in firebug console, since i am using an ordinary gridview which don't have client instance name, i don't think javascript will recognize a grid just by it's name and can't call for GetSelectedRowCount method as well. this might work if we use a gridview from devexpress or some other external components.

Comment: yes i know that, but you can use some other method to check if some row is selected, it at all thats required in your case. but you can surely show the delete confirmation the way i have done it i.e through the onchange() event of the dropdownlist